# Force Item To Bottom Of Page Except for Margin

Tags: html, css

I have a really simple question: How do I force a div to have the largest height it can, while keeping some padding on the bottom. Normaly, I would use:

```css
min-height: 100%;
```

However this completely removes any margin at the bottom of the div (The div always reaches ALL the way to the bottom). I need a small amount of margin at the bottom, however no amount `margin-bottom` will change that. I could make the `min-height` something like `90%`, but I really want the margin bottom to be a fixed value (15px). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc(100% - [margin-bottom])` like so:

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
  min-height:calc(100% - 5em);
  margin-bottom:5em;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: [calc() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())